# jq filter: show whole structure with selection

Tags: json, jq

I have following file1 json:

```
{
  "name": "eye",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "name": "Width",
      "value": "1920"
    },
    {
      "name": "Height",
      "value": "1080"
    },
    {
      "name": "WinKeyMapping",
      "value": "leftwin"
    }
  ],
  "starts": [
    {
      "name": "step1",
      "attributeList": [
        {
          "name": "Command",
          "value": "bash"
        },
        {
          "name": "Test",
          "value": "none"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and following filter:

```
$ jq '.starts[].attributeList[]|select(.name=="Command")' file1
{
  "name": "Command",
  "value": "bash"
}
$
```

how could I get whole structure to this selection?

expected output:

```
{
  "starts": [
    {
      "attributeList": [
        {
          "name": "Command",
          "value": "bash"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straightforwardly with **`jq`**:

```
jq '{ starts: [ { attributeList: (.starts[].attributeList 
                                  | map(select(.name == "Command"))) }] }' file.json
```

The output:

```
{
  "starts": [
    {
      "attributeList": [
        {
          "name": "Command",
          "value": "bash"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thank you. would it be feasible to "extract" from a huge json all such paths+attributes and save each into separate file named related with the path+attribname - e.g. for example above: starts.attributeList.Command.json ?

Comment: @DonJ, welcome, your new description is the case for another question

Comment: I am trying to collect all attributes which are modified by WebUI (for future usage via REST API). For this case, I GET default json (configuration) and after that did changes via WebUI of the configuration and again GET changed configuration. Thanks to you I have already extracted all attributes from the two big json files to single json files, compared them one by one and now I know which ones were modified (there are tens). do you maybe know how to merge this modified now back to sigle file so I can use it at one REST API PUT command?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options to obtain your desired output.

You can delete the keys you don't want:

```
jq 'del(.attributes, .name) | 
  .starts[].attributeList = map(.[].attributeList[] | select(.name == "Command"))'
```

Or you can select only the key(s) you do want:

```
jq 'to_entries | map(select(.key == "starts")) | from_entries | 
  .starts[].attributeList = map(.[].attributeList[] | select(.name == "Command"))'
```

Both give the same result. Also if you wanted `starts` and `ends` in the latter case, you could just add additional `or` statements: `map(select((.key == "starts") or (.key == "ends")))`.

Answer (score 0):

A more generic approach with `jq`:

```
def pick_out(q): path(q) as $path | ($path | length) as $length |
    delpaths(
        [
            paths(..) |
            select(length <= $length and $path[0:length] != . )
        ]
    );
```

This is a `jq` function that deletes all the paths of the document that does not lie anywhere on the path of the given argument, which may be a `select()` call.

Saving this in `pick_out.jq`, we may use it like so:

```bsh
jq 'include "pick_out";
    pick_out(
        .starts[].attributeList[] | select(.name == "Command")
    )' file.json
```

The output:

```json
{
  "starts": [
    {
      "attributeList": [
        {
          "name": "Command",
          "value": "bash"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```